# Mysql query filter results

Tags: mysql

i don't find a solution for this and need a good tip.

This is the table:

```
Name,Status
A, 3
A, 4
B, 3
```

I like do get all results where Status is like 3 but never got Status=4.

In this example: only B should be shown.
How should my query look like? 
Thank you!!

Comment: Select * from table where status =3; try this

Comment: This would also show "A"- But A also has an entry status =4. And should not be shown. I like to see only the ones, who have not an entry =3 AND =4. Only the ones which have 3 only.

Comment: so yes it will give results where status is only 3. if you want to get want to you need to chnage your query select * from table where name ='A'; it will give status 3 and 4 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.Name
from my_table t
where t.Status in (3,4)
group by t.Status
having group_concat(t.Status) = '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select t1.* 
from tableName t1
where t1.status =3 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                   FROM TableName t2
                                   WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND t2.status = 4)
```